# Какое рекордное количество посещений сайта подряд?

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange

Вопрос 1: Каков рекорд по количеству посещений нашего сайта подряд? (и кто его установил?)

Вопрос 2:Каков рекорд по количеству посещений подряд во всем SE?

[MSE аналог](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143842/record-for-most-consecutive-days-visited)

Comment: Вы про количество дней подряд?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Ага.

Comment: Не исключено, что рекорд тут я ставил (точно не помню, но вроде бы больше 1.5 лет ежедневных посещений было). В данный момент - 575 дней.

Comment: Ну вот, заинтересовал, надо будет как-нибудь посчитать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, у тебя [1050](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ntS.png), а у меня только [841](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vrLn.png). Зато у меня все пропуски однодневные :) А если бы 16 июля 2016 не пропустил, у меня было бы 1213.

Comment: Посчитано вот так: `var first, days = 0, res = [];

for (var y = +Object.keys(visited)[0]; y <= 2020; ++y) {
  for (var m = 1; m <= 12; ++m) {
    for (var d = 1; d <= 31; ++d) {
      if (visited[y]?.[m]?.[d]) {
        days++ || (first = new Date(y, m-1, d));
      } else if (days && new Date(y, m-1, d).getDate() === d) {
        res.push({ first: first.toLocaleDateString(), last: new Date(y, m-1, d-1).toLocaleDateString(), days });
        days = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.table(res);
console.log(Math.max(...res.map(x => x.days)));`

Comment: @Qwertiy, круто! У меня пропуск в 2 недели, т.к. я в глубоком заполярье был - там интернета нету( Если б не уезжал, то у меня было б в сумме ~1650)

Comment: Мне мой профиль пишет «На сайте 1740 дней, из них 1148 подряд»

Comment: @andreymal, да, уже на 1 больше :) Интересно что до этой серии в основном были короткие промежутки, а потом раз и 1149)))

Comment: 758 дней. В самом начале один день пропустил, а то было бы ежедневно с самой регистрации.

Comment: @andreymal, ни фига себе! Не надо было мне тогда на севера уезжать(

Comment: [На сайте 1781 день, из них 1761 подряд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/aleksandr-barakin?tab=profile). кто больше?

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Не хило...

Comment: ссылку еще не приводили? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143842/298597

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вкладку SO в браузере закрепил? :)

Comment: @teran У меня вкладка SO стоит второй — сразу после гугла ;)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вероятно, никто, так что поздравляю! :)

Comment: А слабо написать скрипт, чтоб пару раз в день заходил? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Собрал статистику по 1044 топовым участникам на данный момент (3 марта 2020).

Лидирует [aleksandr barakin](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/aleksandr-barakin) - у него 1766 дней подряд (и 1786 всего).

Остальные результаты перечислены в таблице:

- `i` - место по максимальному числу дней подряд
- `max` - само это количество дней
- `cur` - количество дней в серии, заканчивающейся сегодня или вчера
- `pos` - место на сайте по репутации за всё время
- `rep` - репутация участника
- `id` - id участника
- `name` - имя участника

Из таблицы убраны участники с максимальной серией менее 90 дней при условии что они не посещали сайт ни вчера, ни сегодня. Так же убраны 43 участника, данных по которым нет (думаю, они с Хэшкода и не заходили на ruSO ни разу, но не проверял эту гипотезу).

Я скрыл id и имя, поскольку информация вроде как приватная.
Если кто-то хочет показать себя в этом списке, то напишите об этом в комментарии к ответу.

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬────────┐
│    i │  max │  cur │  pos │    rep │   id   │ name
├──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼────────┤
│    1 │ 1766 │ 1766 │   11 │  59936 │ 178576 │ aleksandr barakin
│    2 │ 1233 │    9 │   43 │  23139 │ 176217 │ αλεχολυτ
│    3 │ 1184 │  275 │      │        │        │ 
│    4 │ 1158 │ 1158 │  119 │  10327 │ 178213 │ andreymal
│    5 │ 1156 │ 1156 │   73 │  15623 │ 217579 │ 0xdb
│    6 │ 1151 │ 1151 │      │        │        │ 
│    7 │ 1123 │ 1123 │      │        │        │ 
│    8 │ 1050 │  585 │    9 │  63036 │  17609 │ ЮрийСПб
│    9 │ 1038 │   78 │      │        │        │ 
│   10 │ 1012 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   11 │  977 │  977 │      │        │        │ 
│   12 │  940 │  940 │      │        │        │ 
│   13 │  898 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│   14 │  875 │  171 │      │        │        │ 
│   15 │  874 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│   16 │  864 │  864 │   50 │  21518 │ 179763 │ tym32167
│   17 │  841 │   55 │    4 │  91359 │ 178988 │ Qwertiy
│   18 │  800 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   19 │  782 │  330 │      │        │        │ 
│   20 │  766 │  766 │  107 │  11053 │ 282277 │ Эникейщик
│   21 │  750 │   25 │      │        │        │ 
│   22 │  737 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   23 │  711 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   24 │  695 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│   25 │  678 │  678 │      │        │        │ 
│   26 │  663 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   27 │  651 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│   28 │  649 │   27 │      │        │        │ 
│   29 │  615 │    5 │      │        │        │ 
│   30 │  610 │  610 │      │        │        │ 
│   31 │  583 │  122 │      │        │        │ 
│   32 │  570 │  570 │      │        │        │ 
│   33 │  563 │   49 │      │        │        │ 
│   34 │  541 │   63 │      │        │        │ 
│   35 │  529 │   40 │      │        │        │ 
│   36 │  518 │  518 │      │        │        │ 
│   37 │  509 │   10 │      │        │        │ 
│   38 │  508 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   39 │  495 │   65 │      │        │        │ 
│   40 │  489 │  113 │      │        │        │ 
│   41 │  488 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│   42 │  478 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│   43 │  463 │  463 │      │        │        │ 
│   44 │  454 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│   45 │  449 │  162 │      │        │        │ 
│   46 │  437 │   16 │      │        │        │ 
│   47 │  434 │  434 │      │        │        │ 
│   48 │  432 │    6 │      │        │        │ 
│   49 │  430 │   31 │      │        │        │ 
│   50 │  419 │   31 │      │        │        │ 
│   51 │  408 │   80 │      │        │        │ 
│   52 │  406 │    9 │      │        │        │ 
│   53 │  401 │    7 │      │        │        │ 
│   54 │  398 │  204 │      │        │        │ 
│   55 │  391 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│   56 │  385 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│   57 │  381 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   58 │  372 │  194 │      │        │        │ 
│   59 │  372 │    9 │      │        │        │ 
│   60 │  370 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   61 │  369 │   31 │      │        │        │ 
│   62 │  365 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   63 │  360 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   64 │  346 │  120 │      │        │        │ 
│   65 │  337 │   80 │      │        │        │ 
│   66 │  335 │   11 │      │        │        │ 
│   67 │  333 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│   68 │  331 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   69 │  331 │   26 │      │        │        │ 
│   70 │  328 │  222 │      │        │        │ 
│   71 │  315 │  122 │      │        │        │ 
│   72 │  314 │   88 │      │        │        │ 
│   73 │  314 │    7 │      │        │        │ 
│   74 │  312 │  154 │      │        │        │ 
│   75 │  309 │  298 │      │        │        │ 
│   76 │  307 │   75 │      │        │        │ 
│   77 │  305 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   78 │  299 │  113 │      │        │        │ 
│   79 │  298 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   80 │  294 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   81 │  294 │  256 │   47 │  22770 │   1365 │ insolor
│   82 │  288 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   83 │  285 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   84 │  284 │   86 │      │        │        │ 
│   85 │  283 │  283 │  164 │   8018 │ 339283 │ nomnoms12
│   86 │  272 │  107 │      │        │        │ 
│   87 │  269 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   88 │  260 │    5 │      │        │        │ 
│   89 │  256 │   58 │      │        │        │ 
│   90 │  254 │  254 │      │        │        │ 
│   91 │  253 │  105 │      │        │        │ 
│   92 │  239 │  178 │      │        │        │ 
│   93 │  238 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   94 │  233 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│   95 │  232 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│   96 │  227 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│   97 │  226 │  155 │  175 │   7596 │ 222542 │ Bulson
│   98 │  226 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   99 │  226 │    7 │      │        │        │ 
│  100 │  223 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  101 │  223 │  223 │      │        │        │ 
│  102 │  222 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  103 │  221 │    4 │      │        │        │ 
│  104 │  220 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  105 │  217 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  106 │  216 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  107 │  216 │  216 │      │        │        │ 
│  108 │  211 │   16 │      │        │        │ 
│  109 │  210 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  110 │  209 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  111 │  208 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  112 │  207 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  113 │  206 │   16 │      │        │        │ 
│  114 │  201 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  115 │  200 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  116 │  199 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  117 │  199 │   10 │      │        │        │ 
│  118 │  198 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  119 │  197 │    5 │      │        │        │ 
│  120 │  195 │    6 │      │        │        │ 
│  121 │  194 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  122 │  187 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  123 │  187 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  124 │  185 │   31 │      │        │        │ 
│  125 │  184 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  126 │  184 │  159 │      │        │        │ 
│  127 │  184 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  128 │  180 │   99 │      │        │        │ 
│  129 │  180 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  130 │  179 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  131 │  178 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  132 │  175 │   86 │      │        │        │ 
│  133 │  175 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  134 │  174 │   63 │      │        │        │ 
│  135 │  174 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  136 │  172 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  137 │  171 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  138 │  171 │  171 │ 1018 │   1561 │ 301472 │ SKIP
│  139 │  170 │    9 │      │        │        │ 
│  140 │  169 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  141 │  168 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  142 │  167 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  143 │  166 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  144 │  166 │  166 │      │        │        │ 
│  145 │  165 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  146 │  165 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  147 │  165 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  148 │  164 │   15 │      │        │        │ 
│  149 │  162 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  150 │  161 │    8 │      │        │        │ 
│  151 │  160 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  152 │  159 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  153 │  159 │   21 │      │        │        │ 
│  154 │  157 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  155 │  155 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  156 │  155 │   45 │      │        │        │ 
│  157 │  154 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  158 │  153 │   15 │      │        │        │ 
│  159 │  153 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  160 │  152 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  161 │  151 │   27 │      │        │        │ 
│  162 │  151 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  163 │  151 │    6 │      │        │        │ 
│  164 │  151 │   36 │      │        │        │ 
│  165 │  150 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  166 │  150 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  167 │  150 │   92 │      │        │        │ 
│  168 │  148 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  169 │  148 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  170 │  147 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  171 │  147 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  172 │  147 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  173 │  144 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  174 │  143 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  175 │  143 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  176 │  142 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  177 │  142 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  178 │  141 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  179 │  141 │   17 │      │        │        │ 
│  180 │  141 │  100 │      │        │        │ 
│  181 │  139 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  182 │  139 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  183 │  139 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  184 │  138 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  185 │  137 │    8 │      │        │        │ 
│  186 │  137 │   38 │      │        │        │ 
│  187 │  137 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  188 │  136 │   12 │      │        │        │ 
│  189 │  136 │   23 │      │        │        │ 
│  190 │  136 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  191 │  136 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  192 │  134 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  193 │  134 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  194 │  134 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  195 │  133 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  196 │  132 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  197 │  132 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  198 │  132 │   89 │      │        │        │ 
│  199 │  132 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  200 │  131 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  201 │  131 │   10 │      │        │        │ 
│  202 │  131 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  203 │  131 │   14 │      │        │        │ 
│  204 │  130 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  205 │  130 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  206 │  130 │   55 │      │        │        │ 
│  207 │  129 │    8 │      │        │        │ 
│  208 │  128 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  209 │  127 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  210 │  127 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  211 │  127 │   46 │      │        │        │ 
│  212 │  127 │    9 │      │        │        │ 
│  213 │  127 │  127 │  580 │   2598 │ 337540 │ Victor VosMottor thanks Monica
│  214 │  127 │   10 │      │        │        │ 
│  215 │  126 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  216 │  126 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  217 │  125 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  218 │  125 │   51 │      │        │        │ 
│  219 │  125 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  220 │  124 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  221 │  124 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  222 │  124 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  223 │  123 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  224 │  123 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  225 │  123 │   55 │      │        │        │ 
│  226 │  123 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  227 │  123 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  228 │  122 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  229 │  122 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  230 │  122 │   96 │      │        │        │ 
│  231 │  122 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  232 │  121 │  121 │      │        │        │ 
│  233 │  121 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  234 │  121 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  235 │  121 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  236 │  121 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  237 │  121 │    5 │      │        │        │ 
│  238 │  121 │   18 │      │        │        │ 
│  239 │  121 │  121 │      │        │        │ 
│  240 │  121 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  241 │  121 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  242 │  120 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  243 │  120 │   67 │      │        │        │ 
│  244 │  120 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  245 │  120 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  246 │  120 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  247 │  119 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  248 │  118 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  249 │  118 │    9 │      │        │        │ 
│  250 │  118 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  251 │  117 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  252 │  117 │    4 │      │        │        │ 
│  253 │  116 │  115 │      │        │        │ 
│  254 │  116 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  255 │  116 │   38 │      │        │        │ 
│  256 │  115 │   20 │      │        │        │ 
│  257 │  115 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  258 │  115 │  115 │      │        │        │ 
│  259 │  115 │    5 │      │        │        │ 
│  260 │  115 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  261 │  115 │    9 │      │        │        │ 
│  262 │  114 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  263 │  114 │   11 │      │        │        │ 
│  264 │  114 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  265 │  114 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  266 │  114 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  267 │  114 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  268 │  113 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  269 │  113 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  270 │  113 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  271 │  113 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  272 │  112 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  273 │  112 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  274 │  112 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  275 │  111 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  276 │  111 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  277 │  111 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  278 │  111 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  279 │  110 │   13 │      │        │        │ 
│  280 │  110 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  281 │  110 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  282 │  110 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  283 │  109 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  284 │  109 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  285 │  109 │   60 │      │        │        │ 
│  286 │  109 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  287 │  108 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  288 │  108 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  289 │  108 │    4 │      │        │        │ 
│  290 │  107 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  291 │  107 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  292 │  107 │    9 │      │        │        │ 
│  293 │  107 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  294 │  107 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  295 │  107 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  296 │  107 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  297 │  106 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  298 │  106 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  299 │  106 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  300 │  106 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  301 │  106 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  302 │  106 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  303 │  106 │   17 │      │        │        │ 
│  304 │  106 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  305 │  105 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  306 │  105 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  307 │  105 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  308 │  105 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  309 │  105 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  310 │  104 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  311 │  104 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  312 │  104 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  313 │  104 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  314 │  103 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  315 │  103 │    4 │      │        │        │ 
│  316 │  103 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  317 │  103 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  318 │  103 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  319 │  103 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  320 │  103 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  321 │  103 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  322 │  102 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  323 │  102 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  324 │  101 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  325 │  101 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  326 │  101 │    7 │      │        │        │ 
│  327 │  100 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  328 │  100 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  329 │  100 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  330 │  100 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  331 │  100 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  332 │  100 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  333 │   98 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  334 │   97 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  335 │   97 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  336 │   96 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  337 │   96 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  338 │   96 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  339 │   96 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  340 │   96 │   11 │      │        │        │ 
│  341 │   96 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  342 │   95 │   95 │      │        │        │ 
│  343 │   94 │   60 │      │        │        │ 
│  344 │   93 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  345 │   93 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  346 │   91 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│  347 │   90 │   80 │      │        │        │ 
│  348 │   90 │   90 │      │        │        │ 
│  349 │   90 │    6 │      │        │        │ 
│  350 │   90 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  353 │   88 │   19 │      │        │        │ 
│  355 │   87 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  356 │   87 │    8 │      │        │        │ 
│  358 │   86 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  359 │   85 │    5 │      │        │        │ 
│  363 │   83 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  364 │   83 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  366 │   82 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  369 │   82 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  372 │   80 │   38 │      │        │        │ 
│  373 │   80 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  376 │   78 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  379 │   77 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  380 │   77 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  383 │   77 │    4 │      │        │        │ 
│  385 │   76 │   76 │      │        │        │ 
│  392 │   75 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  400 │   73 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  402 │   73 │   73 │      │        │        │ 
│  403 │   72 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  405 │   72 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  407 │   71 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  412 │   69 │   58 │      │        │        │ 
│  413 │   68 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  415 │   66 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  425 │   65 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  429 │   64 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  430 │   63 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  431 │   63 │   10 │      │        │        │ 
│  437 │   62 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  440 │   62 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  442 │   61 │   55 │      │        │        │ 
│  448 │   60 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  451 │   60 │   52 │      │        │        │ 
│  452 │   60 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  453 │   59 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  454 │   59 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  457 │   58 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  458 │   58 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  465 │   56 │   56 │      │        │        │ 
│  471 │   56 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  480 │   55 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  481 │   55 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  484 │   54 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  486 │   54 │    8 │      │        │        │ 
│  491 │   53 │   15 │      │        │        │ 
│  493 │   53 │   53 │      │        │        │ 
│  495 │   52 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  497 │   51 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  498 │   51 │   10 │      │        │        │ 
│  506 │   49 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  509 │   48 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  510 │   48 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  512 │   48 │   48 │      │        │        │ 
│  524 │   47 │   11 │      │        │        │ 
│  526 │   46 │    5 │      │        │        │ 
│  527 │   46 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  534 │   45 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  537 │   44 │   44 │      │        │        │ 
│  538 │   44 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  546 │   43 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  547 │   43 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  551 │   42 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  554 │   42 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  555 │   42 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  557 │   42 │   42 │      │        │        │ 
│  559 │   41 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  562 │   41 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  566 │   41 │    4 │      │        │        │ 
│  569 │   40 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  573 │   39 │   10 │      │        │        │ 
│  577 │   38 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  578 │   38 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  580 │   38 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  586 │   36 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  592 │   35 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  595 │   35 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  597 │   34 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  598 │   34 │    5 │      │        │        │ 
│  606 │   34 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  607 │   34 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  609 │   34 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  611 │   33 │    8 │      │        │        │ 
│  613 │   33 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  616 │   33 │   10 │      │        │        │ 
│  620 │   33 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  622 │   33 │   33 │      │        │        │ 
│  623 │   33 │    7 │      │        │        │ 
│  624 │   32 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  625 │   32 │    4 │      │        │        │ 
│  627 │   32 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  633 │   31 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  637 │   31 │    4 │      │        │        │ 
│  640 │   31 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  641 │   31 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  643 │   31 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  645 │   30 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  652 │   28 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  662 │   27 │    9 │      │        │        │ 
│  669 │   26 │   17 │      │        │        │ 
│  672 │   26 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  678 │   26 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  687 │   24 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  699 │   22 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  707 │   21 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  709 │   21 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  714 │   21 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  717 │   20 │   19 │      │        │        │ 
│  721 │   20 │    7 │      │        │        │ 
│  731 │   19 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  735 │   18 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  737 │   18 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  740 │   18 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│  767 │   14 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  775 │   13 │    4 │      │        │        │ 
│  779 │   13 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  782 │   13 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  793 │   12 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  807 │   12 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  816 │   11 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  825 │    9 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  830 │    9 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  835 │    9 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  836 │    9 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│  867 │    6 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  886 │    5 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│  972 │    2 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Пока показаны только те, кто уже писал под вопросом.

Comment: Я набрал 126, а таких в списке нет. Почему?
Если можно, добавьте меня тоже.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, да, у тебя 126. Ты на 580м месте, а статистика только по top 256. Возможно, стоило больше участников взять? Впрочем, добавил, только без места.

Comment: У меня сейчас 256 дней подряд (круглое число)), возможно было и больше. Добавьте меня)

Comment: А как определяется, что пользователь посетил сайт? По самому наличию запроса? Или нужно провести N времени на сайте/должна быть какая-то активность

Comment: @insolor, у тебя максимум 294 - добавил.

Comment: @ThisMan, скорее всего просто посетить. Но точно сказать не могу. И где-то была информация, что главная страница не считается.

Comment: "у него 1765 дней подряд (и 1785 всего)" ... ай-яй-яй ... 20 дней где-то пропадал. А все присутствующие тут страдали всё это время. Нехорошо.

Comment: Было бы интересно ещё получить максимальную по участнику (хотя бы свою собственную). А не состояние на текущий момент.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, в таблице и есть максимальные. Вообще да, наверное стоит ещё текущую добавить. Показать тебя в таблице? Кстати, свои собственные периоды можно узнать запустив соответствующий скрипт в консоли браузера на странице профиля после открытия календаря.

Comment: Можно и добавить меня. Я не возражаю. Почему-то думал, что именно текущая в таблице, а не максимальная.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, обновил таблицу.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, обновил.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, готово, второе место.

Comment: Можно и меня, пожалуйста :D (`283/283`).

Comment: @insolor, готово. У меня есть полная таблица с именами. Только я места с 0 пронумеровал :( В опубликованном поправил

Comment: А почему эта информация приватная? Да, числу дней подряд не показывается в чужом профиле. Но что такого личного можно выудить из этой информации об участнике? Думаю ничего, занесите и меня пожалуйста -  пятачок.

Comment: @0xdb это как-то странно, но на одном из сайтов, который я админю, тоже имеются несколько пользователей, которые против даже отображения последнего визита выступают непонятно почему

Comment: @andreymal Зависит от специфики сайта. Здесь по времени последнего визита можно сделать вывод, что автор вопроса/ответа вероятно вернётся в скором времени и ему можно,например, написать комментарий. Какую информацию несёт число дней подряд, если неизвестно, когда этот период начался, и когда закончился?

Comment: @0xdb, добавил. Не знаю, можно спросить где-нибудь. Текущий период тоже в таблице, кстати.

Comment: @Qwertiy А зачем спрашивать? Спасибо!

Comment: @0xdb, на всякий случай.

Comment: @Qwertiy Можно. Думал,что модераторы и так знают.

Comment: А можно меня отразить в этом списке?

Comment: @Bulson, готово, 97й.

Comment: ну и меня в телевизор добавь, пусть все узрят, что я модератора обогнал :)

Comment: спасибо........

Comment: @tym32167, 16й - круглое число :) И можно ещё восьмерых обогнать, правда, небыстро).

Comment: @
tym32167
, длина сообщения ограничена, пришлось хвост подчистить. К тому же, хвост - так себе рейтинг. Участников у нас гораздо больше 1044, так что с такими результатами там может быть полно народу. А вот топ я думаю достаточно правильный.

Comment: @Qwertiy я тоже не откажусь от такой чести)

Comment: @SKIP, 171 день - 138й.

Comment: А почему 1044? Можно было покруглее число взять — 1024, например.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, да, я и хотел 1024, но страницы с рейтингом участников сделаны по 36, так что это следующее кратное 36.

Comment: @Qwertiy Кстати давай сделаем такой список и для нашей  меты.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, не уверен, что для меты прокатит использовать репутацию основного сайта в качестве ограничения...

Comment: Вот еще похожий вопрос про тревоги. Какой-нибудь скрипт для него напишите?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10262/%d0%a3-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3

Answer (score 5):

Модераторы могут посчитать статистику по top 1044 участникам следующим скриптом:

```
Promise.all(Array(29).fill().map((x,p) => fetch(`/users?page=${p+1}&tab=reputation&filter=all`).then(resp => resp.text()).then(page => {
  return [...new DOMParser().parseFromString(page, "text/html").querySelectorAll(".user-details")].map(u => {
    var a = u.querySelector("a")
    var rep = u.querySelector(".reputation-score")

    return {
      pos: 0,
      id: +a.href.match(/\d+/),
      name: a.textContent,
      rep: +(rep.title.match(/[\d+,]+/)?.[0] || rep.textContent).replace(/,/g, ""),
    }
  })
}))).then(pages => {
  data = pages.flat()
  data.forEach((x, i) => x.pos = i+1)

  var wnd = window.open()
  wnd.document.write("<plaintext>" + JSON.stringify(data))
  wnd.document.close()

  if (new Set(data.map(x => x.id)).size !== data.length) throw new Error("Duplicate ids found")

  console.table(data)
  return data
}).then(() => Promise.all(data.map(u => fetch(`/users/daily-site-access/${u.id}`, {credentials:"include"}).then(r => r.text()).then(x => u.visits = eval("("+x.match(/var visited = (.*);/)[1]+")"))))).then(() => {
  wnd = window.open()
  wnd.document.write("<plaintext>" + JSON.stringify(data))
  wnd.document.close()

  result = []

  var date = new Date()
  var cury = date.getUTCFullYear(), curm = date.getUTCMonth(), curd = date.getUTCDay()

  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)
  var prevy = date.getUTCFullYear(), prevm = date.getUTCMonth(), prevd = date.getUTCDay()

  for (var u of data) {
    var visits = u.visits
    var first, days = 0, res = []

    for (var y = +Object.keys(visits)[0]; y <= cury; ++y) {
      for (var m = 1; m <= 12; ++m) {
        for (var d = 1; d <= 31; ++d) {
          if (visits[y]?.[m]?.[d]) {
            days++ || (first = new Date(y, m-1, d));
          } else if (days && new Date(y, m-1, d).getDate() === d) {
            res.push({ first: first.toLocaleDateString(), last: new Date(y, m-1, d-1).toLocaleDateString(), days })
            days = 0
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // console.table(res)
    result.push({ max: Math.max(0, ...res.map(x => x.days)), cur: (visits[cury]?.[curm]?.[curd] || visits[prevy]?.[prevm]?.[prevd]) && res[res.length-1]?.days || 0, ...u })
  }

  console.table(result)

  result.sort((x,y) => y.max-x.max)
  console.table(result)

  visible = new Set([178576,176217,178213,17609,178988,282277,1365,339283,337540])

  fields = [
    { f: "max",  ps: 4, pe: 0 },
    { f: "cur",  ps: 4, pe: 0 },
    { f: "pos",  ps: 4, pe: 0 },
    { f: "rep",  ps: 6, pe: 0 },
    { f: "id",   ps: 6, pe: 0 },
    { f: "name", ps: 0, pe: 0 },
  ]

  var cleaned = false

  while (1) {
    console.log(
`┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬────────┐
│    i │  max │  cur │  pos │    rep │   id   │ name
├──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼────────┤
${result.map((x,i)=>`│ ${(i+1+"").padStart(4)} │ ${fields.map(({f,ps,pe}) => (x[f]+"").padStart(ps).padEnd(pe)).join(" │ ")}`).join("\n")}
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴────────┘`)

    if (cleaned) break
    var cleaned = true

    for (var x of result) {
      if (!visible.has(x.id)) {
        x.pos = x.id = x.name = x.rep = ""
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Promise.all это уже DoS-атака какая-то)

Comment: @andreymal, браузер сгруппирует не более 6 одновременно, но в целом да, запросы шлются подряд. Я вообще хотел какой-нибудь wget или curl использовать, но что-то у меня ничего не взлетело - похоже, я куки не умею правильно передавать.