# У кого наибольшее количество полезных тревог?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги, статистика

Сегодня у меня 1000 полезных тревог. По такому случаю решил спросить:

- У кого на ru.SO наибольшее количество полезных тревог?
- У кого на Meta.ru.SO наибольшее количество полезных тревог?
- У кого на en.SO наибольшее количество полезных тревог?
- У кого на всем SE наибольшее количество полезных тревог?

Comment: Список вахтеров в студию!

Comment: У нас всего [38 участников имеют 500+ полезных тревог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal). А на мете [всего 2 с 80+](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/70/deputy). И данные по числу полезных тревог открытые.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Promise.all([...document.querySelectorAll(".single-badge-user .user-details a")].map(a => fetch(a.href).then(resp => resp.text()).then(html => ({ id: +a.href.match(/\d+/)[0], name: a.textContent.trim(), flags: +html.match(/href="\/users\/flag-summary\/[^>]+>([\d,]+)/)[1].replace(/,/g, "") })))).then(data => console.table(data = (window.data || []).concat(data).sort((x, y) => y.flags - x.flags))+console.log(`data=${JSON.stringify(data)}`))
```

## ruSO, участники со знаком [Прокурор](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal) (500+ полезных тревог)

[image: данные по ruSO]

## metaRuSO, участники со знаком [Дружинник](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8?page=1) (1+ тревогa)

[image: данные по metaRuSO]

Comment: Класс!9 символов нужно...

Comment: Блин.. Ромбики посеял :(

Comment: Хм.. муть какая-то с модераторами.

Comment: А под индексом 0, это кто?  Бот что-ли?

Comment: @0xdb, у нас вроде ботов нет? На скриншоте же id есть - вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/305099/mattallegro.

Comment: @Qwertiy  Да я то уже посмотрел. И как можно без какой либо другой активности на сайте столько тревог навешать? Раз не бот, значит спортсмен.

Comment: @0xdb, не знаю, но у него все тревоги на комментариях, полезных 2563, а отклонённых только 2. Вряд ли бот бы имел всего 0.08% ошибок. Хотя, может он "спасибо" сносит массово.

Comment: @Qwertiy "спасибо" и "thanks" тревогает.

Comment: Кстати сносом "спасибо" часто занимаюсь я: заметил, что если поставить на комментарий со словом спасибо тревогу, он удалиться автоматически (ну по-крайне мере очень быстро — сразу).

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, да, автоматически :(

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, потому что https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7102/178988