# Не полностью переведён интерфейс тревог

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, закрытие-вопросов

Не полностью переведён <s>междумордие</s> интерфейс тревог:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну как, появились строки?

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik [Ага](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoDMG.png). [tag:статус-завершено]

Comment: Галочку ещё на ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ага, сегодня в [чате уже репортили](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54088413#54088413).

Добавил переводы. Завтра появятся на сайте.

Comment: А то теперь за 3k репы я имею право голосовать за закрытие и в список полезных тревог мне закрытые вопросы не добавляются. А я уж вознамерился побить [рекорд](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10262/%d0%a3-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3) по кол-ву полезных тревог. Так что перекинулся на ответы и комменты. Даже спорные ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica удачи (:

Comment: :D 14 символов нужно...

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Тревоги нужны не для того, чтобы мериться их количеством и ставить рекорды. Малое количество тревог — это даже хорошо. Не переусердствуйте :)

Comment: @nomnoms12 ну, почему же. Полезные тревоги мы приветствуем.